# Scrape text under div tag that is in quotes

Tags: scrapy

Trying to scrape this part: "Lounge, Showers, Lockers"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5mzg.png

```
<div class="CourseAbout-otherFacilities more"> 
           <h3 class="CourseAbout-otherFacilities-title">Available Facilities</h3> " Lounge, Showers, Lockers "
          </div>
```

Website:
https://www.golfadvisor.com/courses/16929-black-at-bethpage-state-park-golf-course

`response.css('.CourseAbout-foodAndBeverage.more::text').get()` command returns " \n           "

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **three** text elements in your target `div` (matched by your CSS expression):

```
<div class="CourseAbout-otherFacilities more">FIRST<h3
<h3 class="CourseAbout-otherFacilities-title">SECOND</h3>
</h3>THIRD</div>
```

By using `.get()` you're telling Scrapy to return **first** match.

I recommend to use XPath expression here instead and match your element by text:

```
//h3[.="Available Facilities"]/following-sibling::text()[1]'
```

Comment: Clear as a day. Thank you! Why would you suggest using xpath instead?

Comment: Because with XPath you can match element by **text**. Also internal markup may change by time.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you.